# Mouse and keyboard unresponsive on login screen; cannot switch to tty

Tags: release-hera, greeter, keyboard, mouse

So out of the blue my elementaryOS 5.1 has stopped responding on the login screen. Whereas yesterday everything worked perfectly fine, today I get stuck because both mouse and keyboard stop working entirely. Pressing ctrl-alt-f2 to switch to a different tty also yields no response.

The problem does not lie with the peripherals. They work perfectly fine in the BIOS, and I can navigate the grub boot menu just fine. It looks more like the entire system just crashes as soon as the login screen shows up? The cursor for entering the password to login is initially blinking, but stops and freezes after a few seconds.

I have not updated anything, nor installed any new software. I have ample space, my harddrive is half empty. I've found no solutions to this problem, and no person experiencing the exact same issue.

Comment: I am not in your situation, but I noticed that from some time, the login screen does not reacts right away to the pressed keys and you have to wait a few seconds before typing your password. Some other times, you can just start to type your password right way. No big changes from my side, just the regular updates.

Comment: I have the exact same problem after I updated the system. My keyboard works because I can type my password for the encrypted drive. But when the login screen comes both mouse and keyboard stop working. And when keyboard not responding. ctrl-alt-f2 don't work to so how do I enter the command that Benjamin Ye suggested?

Comment: @CryptoFarian Hey, this response may be a few days late, but try booting into Safe Mode at the GRUB menu. You should be prompted with a terminal instance.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact issue. After rebooting my computer, my mouse and keyboard were completely unresponsive and I noticed that a blinking cursor on one of my start-up programs became and stayed solid, suggesting that my entire system had crashed.

I'm not sure if you're still having the issue, but I was able to solve my issue by reinstalling input devices:

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all`